# START TRANSACTION within a stored procedure within a START TRANSACTION mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion, transactions

From the mysql docs, it appears ambiguous as to whether calling

```
START TRANSACTION;
...
COMMIT;
```

from within a subroutine will automatically commit the "progress" of the outer caller's TRANSACTION, or whether it will simply add a reference to the outer caller's TRANSACTION, and wait until the final COMMIT in the outer caller (based on this ref-counting scheme) before the changes actually appear in the data tables.

Which is correct?  Perhaps I'm confused from Googling too much, and just hoping for the nested scenario to be reality...

Additional question: If the nested/ref-counted prescription is not "correct", why was it designed this way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0
```

then

```
START TRANSACTION;
...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Are you saying that before each start transaction, if I set autocommit to 0, it will then behave as I described in the "nested/ref-counted" fashion?

Comment: at first time you set autocommit